# Undefined in store reducer

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to write reducer for action in angular ngrx store architecture:

this is my reducer:

```
export const registration = (state: any, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'REGISTER_USER':
      console.log('reducer ' + payload, type);
      return payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and this is my function calling the reducer

```
register(user: RegistrationUser) {
    return this.http.post(Global.API_URL+'/register', user)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(data => ({type: 'REGISTER_USER', data}))
      .subscribe(action => {this.store.dispatch(action); console.log(action)});
  }
```

the problem Im having in that the payload is undefined. Where the

```
console.log(action);
```

returns object. And console log from reducer returns proper action type but undefined as object 'reducer undefined REGISTER_USER'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to just map data to payload: data:

```
register(user: RegistrationUser) {
    return this.http.post(Global.API_URL+'/register', user)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(data => ({type: 'REGISTER_USER', payload: data}))
      .subscribe(action => {this.store.dispatch(action); console.log(action)});
  }
```